# azure cloud powershell runbook upload in storage account

Tags: azure, powershell

I am uploading the result of some computation to an azure storage account.

I use these statements:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "csb5387a20f4e8cx435ax9b8" -StorageAccountKey "xxxx "

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "azurescan" -File $FileName  -context $context
```

It has worked and this statments still work on the Cloud Shell.

But in the runbook they get the following error-messages, which are not very helpful.

Can anybody help me?

> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : Method not found:
>   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RequestEventArgs.get_Request()'. At
>   line:329 char:5
>   +     Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "azurescan" -File $FileNam ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent], StorageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentCommand

Comment: were you able to fix your issue? I have the same problem on my local machine.